# Windows app's task bar icon is set default

Tags: c++, qt, icons

I'm developing application with QT and my window is created with QDialog. When app state is changed I need to change the app's task bar icon:

`parentWidget()->setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/new.ico"));`

However, in a run-time, if you changed the icon with code above and then make right click to your app's icon (or pin it to taskbar), it will be changed to default one (I suspect to the executable icon).

I found if my icon is reset to default one, I can pin it to taskbar and then unpin back and the icon will be set to the 'new' one.
Is there a way to prevent this somehow and keep the icon always like I want?

Comment: Did you use this in `.pro` file: `win32: RC_ICONS = image.ico`  ?

Comment: how about `QApplication::setWindowIcon(const QIcon &)` did you try it.
I'm not at windows to check this behavior and I think It's windows fault